# How do i add the user image to their name using the return json image link in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

All, I would like to be able to add the user image next to their name when it is found or search.

The search field where the user enters their search and when they click off of it the results is stored in the select field: I have the other user_image select field that I can see the URL for the image, however, I am not sure how to display this image next to the name or even display the image. I am aware of using image_tag but how do I do that in the select option? ... I prefer that it display in the same decisionmaker field which I can return the value there but I am not sure how to add the image tag to view the image from the image URL provided...

[image]

I want something like this:
[image]

'autocomplete'%>

I have the ID:  <%= f.select :decisionmaker, {}, {}, {:class => "form-control", :id => "decisionmaker" , 'data-behavior' => 'autocomplete'}%>

User Image:  <%= f.select :decisionmaker, {}, {}, {:class => "form-control", :id => "user_imag" , 'data-behavior' => 'autocomplete'}%>

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('change', '#createcampaign_decisionmaker', function() {
    var input_state = $(this);
    console.log("khemlall starts")
    var decisionmaker = $("#decisionmaker");
    var user_image= $("#user_image")
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        decisionmaker.html("");
    } else {
      // var key=$("#createcampaign_decisionmaker").val();
        var inputvalue = input_state.val();
        inputvalue = inputvalue.replace(" ", "&");
        console.log(inputvalue)
        var searchurl = '/search/?q='+ inputvalue;
        //$.getJSON('/search/', function(data) {



        $.getJSON(searchurl, function(data) {
            var results = data;

            var opt = '<option value="" selected="">list of user</option>';
            var imageopt  = '<option value="" selected="">list of user</option>';
            if (results.length == 0) {

            } else {
                    //$.each(data.users, function(index, value)
                    //{console.log("index" + index + ": " + value)})

                 $.each(results.users, function(index, value) {

                  // console.log("image url" + value.image.url)
                    opt += '<option>' + value.first_name + " " +  value.last_name + '</option>';
                    imageopt += '<option>'+ value.image.url  + '</option>';
                    user_image.html(imageopt)
                    decisionmaker.html(opt);
                });


            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom selectbox for this.

Create a input field and onChange begin search and after the search is complete just like you were adding options tag. You can append li elements in a ul tag. Here you will need some css to make it look good.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>image tag...</span>
        User name
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>image tag</span>
        User name
    </li>
</ul>
```

For reference check this out (Custom Select Box)
https://jsfiddle.net/fhpf6tpg/9/

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link please check that out. You will get an idea on how to create an Custom Selectbox

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must use Select2 library, it's a good library. Visit https://select2.org/dropdown to look what are you looking for.